# JS - Math isn't coming out right

Tags: javascript, api, dom, parseint

I'm building an app that displays the weather and converts the current temp from Fahrenheit to Celsius. For some reason, when the conversion takes place, the math isn't coming out right. Oddly, after clicking the button 5 - 6 times, it starts working correctly.

My best guess is that I'm doing something wrong with `parseInt()` or maybe a variable isn't being updated.

Thoughts?

```
function toggleUnits(){
  if(wUnit.innerHTML == "C"){
    var oldTemp = parseInt(wTemp.innerHTML, 10),
        newTemp = oldTemp * 9 / 5 + 32;
    wTemp.innerHTML= newTemp;
    wUnit.innerHTML = "F";
    unitToggle.innerHTML ="Switch to Celsius";
  }else{
    var oldTemp = parseInt(wTemp.innerHTML, 10),
        newTemp = (oldTemp-32) * 5 / 9;
    wTemp.innerHTML= newTemp;
    wUnit.innerHTML = "C";
    unitToggle.innerHTML ="Switch to Fahrenheit";
  }
}
```

CodePen: https://codepen.io/abenjamin/pen/ZojJLq

Comment: Seems fine other than Seattle is on fire.

Comment: The code pen correctly converts for me.

Comment: @Clint - Even after the data loads?

Comment: Now it is not on fire and I am guessing you need to learn about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: ObLink: http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: @AaronBenjamin Ah, no. I instinctively click "Block" on those notifications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is helpful to scale up your decimal values by a consistent multiplier and represent all numbers as integers. For example, use `806` degrees instead of `80.6` degrees (multiply by 10) for your temperature calculations. This is to avoid the [nuances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) with floating-point math. In JavaScript we only have the floating-point data type for numeric values, but luckily **integer math under the floating-point data-type is exact**. Therefore scaling up decimal values to integers (e.g., `2550` degrees instead of `25.50` degrees ) resolves the issue.

For example (converting from fahrenheit to celsius):

```
console.log((80.6-32) * 5 / 9); // outputs 26.999999999999996
```

Corrected with:

```
console.log((806-320) * 5 / 9 / 10 ); // outputs 27
```

The reason your calculator works correctly sometimes but not other times is because the temperature API sometimes returns integers, but other times returns decimal values.

I wouldn't recommend using `parseInt` to resolve this issue because it will round decimal values and you'll lose precision.